# How to validate the bootstrap-datetimepicker using jQuery Validate

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql-server, jquery-validate, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am currently using bootstrap datetime picker to handle all date selections in the application. I am using Jquery validation and it works with moment.js.

The input uses a custom knockout binding for the datetime picker.

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-4">Date and Time client received clinical*</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6" data-bind="visible: SubmittedToClientDateNA() === false">
                            <input id="SubmittedToClientDate" name="SubmittedToClientDate" autocomplete="off" type="text" class="ph-datetimepicker form-control" data-bind="dateAndTimePicker: SubmittedToClientDate" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label>
                                    <input id="SubmittedToClientDateNA" name="SubmittedToClientDateNA" type="checkbox" data-bind="click: SetSubmittedToClientDate, checked: SubmittedToClientDateNA">N/A
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Moment.js keeps the date formatted and this js makes sure there is a value.

```
$("#editAuthorizationInformationForm").validate({
            rules: {
                SubmittedToClientDate: { required: true }
            }
        });
```

The problem I am running into is that when the user types in a date like: '12/20/0008', the validation evaluates this as a valid date. However when the value gets back to the server and tries to save it to sql server it throws an error:

"The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value."

Is there a way that I can validate not only the format of the date, but the date itself on the client?

Thank you for your help!

RESOLVED:

I resolved this by adding this custom validator method:

```
$.validator.addMethod("ValidateDateFormat", function (date) {
            var pattern = /(0\d{1}|1[0-2])\/([0-2]\d{1}|3[0-1])\/(19|20)(\d{2})/;
            var m = date.match(pattern);
            if (!m)
                return false;
            var d = new Date(date);
            // Now let's ensure that the date is not out of index
            if (d.getMonth() + 1 == parseInt(m[1], 10) && d.getDate() == parseInt(m[2], 10)) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }, "Please enter a valid date");
```

And applying it to the input field:

```
$("#editAuthorizationInformationForm").validate({
            rules: {
                SubmittedToClientDate: { ValidateDateFormat: true, required: true }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Write a custom rule to validate the date itself.  See the `.addMethod()` method in the documentation.  (*Also, when seeking help with your code, you are strongly encouraged to post the relevant code.  Please review the FAQ.*)

Comment: Hi Sparky, thanks for the reply. I have added some of the code to help others further understand my issue. Are you suggesting that I use the validator.addMethod on the datetime with some sort of regex to validate each part of the date? i.e make sure month value is between 1-12 and day value 1-31, etc.?

Comment: I read the duplicate posts that you linked and unfortunately they do not answer my question.

Comment: I am suggesting that you add another client-side rule to the field to ensure the client-side data is as you need it.  However, since you are trying to prevent a server-side error, it's best to also have some server-side validation code to prevent bad data from being sent to your database in the first place.

Comment: @Sparky Thank you for your help. I have posted my solution in the question above.